# A limit as $x \to 0 $ of a differentiable function

Tags: limits

Given a differentiable function , then what is

$$\lim_{x\to0} \left({ \frac{f(a)}{f(a+x)}}\right)^{\frac2x} $$

Where $a$ is a real number.

If I use the identities $ \ln(1+x) \sim x $

and $ f(a+x) \sim f(a)+xf'(a) $

and take logarithms to both sides my guess is that the limit is

$ \exp\left(- 2\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}\right) .$

Is this method correct with this result ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it that way, with a lot more details.

Alternatively, you can just note that if $g(y)=\log f(y)$, then:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x+a)-g(a)}{x} = g'(a)=\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$$

But $$e^{\frac{g(x+a)-g(a)}{x}} = \left(\frac{f(x+a)}{f(a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

So the $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{f(x+a)}{f(a)}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$$

by continuity of $e^z$.  Finally, your limit is this expression raised to the $-2$ power, so your limit is:$$e^{-2\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}}$$

Comment: (That was probably too much detail for a "homework" answer, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct. You can make your method rigorous using [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).